# I cannot connect to the server with vscode's remote-ssh

Tags: visual-studio-code

I built a virtual ubuntu server with a virtual box. I was connecting well using vscode's remote-ssh.

But from this morning, I suddenly became unable to connect. Initially, it was asked to enter the password indefinitely.

On the server, run the command rm -rf /home/.vscode-server. I got the information that I could rerun vscode and ran it.

Then, the problem of continuing to ask for the password disappeared, but I still couldn't connect.

It does not proceed anymore in the Opening Remote state, and does not proceed after the Downloading with wget message appears in the terminal. I waited more than 20 minutes.

There was an update to Windows over the weekend, but is the latest version of remote-ssh not responding to the update of Windows? I don't know what to look for anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It is working well After I remove Windows Update ver KB5000802 updated at 2021-03-15.